# Chart.js reset zoom button

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I'm using a chart.js API version 3.4.1 and I have a button to reset the graph after zoom. When I click the button the error below returned:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resetZoom is not a function

The HTML code :

```
<canvas id="grafico3" style="background-color: #DCDCDC"></canvas>
<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="resetZoom3();" >Reset Zoom</a>
```

The JS code:

```
function resetZoom3() {
    $("grafico3").resetZoom();
}
```

Does anyone have any idea to reset the chart's zoom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to acces the canvas element, this doesnt contain the chart instance. You will need to call `resetZoom` on the chart instance so where you make your chart by calling `new Chart` you will need to store it in a variable that you can reference to call the reset on.

So you will get something like this:

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);

chart.resetZoom();
```